# Transformation of matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a matrix A in the form

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a &b &c\\
d &e &f\\
g &h &i\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I would like to transform it into

$$\begin{bmatrix}
a &b &c\\
0 &d &e\\
0 &0 &g\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

The simplest solution I've come up with is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &0\\
\end{bmatrix} * A * U^0 + 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 &0\\
0 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &0\\
\end{bmatrix} * A * U^1 + 
\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &0\\
0 &0 &1\\
\end{bmatrix} * A * U^2
$$

where $$U = \begin{bmatrix}
0 &1 &0\\
0 &0 &1\\
0 &0 &0\\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

While this solution works it doesn't scale particularly well as the size of A grows from 3 x 3 to 60 x 60

Comment: What do you mean by "transform"? Is that supposed to be a matrix similar to your original? If so, the diagonal entries must be the eigenvalues of the original. Otherwise, if you're just moving entries around, it doesn't mean much, but that seems to be what you want to do.

Comment: I haven't take linear algebra in about 20 years so I am very rusty with my terminology - transform is not likely the correct word here. I am attempting to shift items around.  This problem stems for my attempt to model a finance problem where I am employee productivity is a function of time and hiring is a function of time as well.  I am looking for a matrix that represents "cross" of those two things.  Matrices may not be the right thing to model this with but it seems to work for many cases

Comment: So are you only allowed matrix operations? You want a 'closed' form that you can then manipulate? If you just want the results of such a matrix, just notate it: $A^{*}_{i,j} = A_{i, i+j}$ or 0 if $i>j$.

Comment: I'm after a 'closed' form that I can manipulate further.  This calculation is one in a series of steps. The other calculations I am making seem to be represented nicely by stringing together multiplication of vectors and matrices.  I am really trying to figure out how to multiply 'discrete functions' together.  E.g. Employee Productivity as a function of time since hire * Number of employees hired per month = Total Company Productivity as a function of time.  There may be a better way to model this problem.

Comment: Maybe this is a coding problem, not a math problem. If so, there's a site for coding questions.